# Fastest way to get money in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I've been playing for a while, but the only problem I have is generally not having enough money. I want to build my house for Hearthfire, but I don't want to spend all my money solely on wood and stone and stuff.
What are some quick ways to get money?

Comment: besides the answers already provided(completing jobs or crafting): the quickest way would probably be to enter "player.additem f <amount>" in the console. but you should be aware that this will disabled achievements for the remainder of the session, restarting the game should fix that though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I was playing Skyrim I had no problems with gold, but that may be due to my style of playing - I always check every chest, urn, dead bodies etc. and after returning home I have a lot of things to sell (not to mention that chests also contain gold).

If you completed The Dark Brotherhood quest you can ask Night Mother for unlimited amount of assasination quests, which result in 1000 gold for a kill. These kills are generally trivial, as they target random pedestrians.

There are also other ways to aquire a lot of gold, like the trick with Khajiit caravans (sell items, kill the merchant, travel on map to this place again and repeat) but in my opinion it's ruining the overall game experience.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get money is through alchemy. Most of the alchemy merchants have alchemy tables in their shop, so you can buy ingredients, craft, sell the resulting potions, then fast travel to the next town and repeat. Be careful to avoid buying expensive ingredients like void salts, fire salts, and especially the daedra heart.

Often when you fast travel to the next town, it'll be night. The best way to wait until morning is to go to the inn and just wait the time in the main hall, don't bother spending money on a room, they don't hassle you for sleeping in the hall.

Be aware that potions will decrease in value as you increase the supply of the potion, alchemy is best used to get the money to start on some other means of making money like making banish-enchanted daggers.

Comment: They've tweaked this stuff in updates, so it might have changed, but it used to be fairly easy to get to the point where visiting each hold, buying all the ingredients, and making as many potions as you could would produce potions worth more than all the gold all the merchants had. It would take a couple days to sell it all off. Basically infinite money if you felt like spending the time on it.